# Efficient algorithm for graph isomorphism between graphs differing in only one edge

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, graph-isomorphism

I am looking for an efficient graph isomorphism algorithm for a special case:

given a simple undirected graph $G$ check whether the graphs $G\cup e_1$ and $G\cup e_2$ are isomorphic. The edges $e_1$ and $e_2$ do not add new vertices, but only connect a pair of unconnected vertices from $V(G)$. If the graph allows isolated vertices then there are obvious special cases. I am particulary interested in the case when $G$ is connected. I would be grateful for at least some special cases. There is an obvious probabilistic algorithm that can give false positives (just compare the degree vectors). I would be happy with one that instead allows false negatives, but never gives false positives.

Comment: You are essentially checking whether there is an automorphism of $G$ that takes the endpoints of $e_1$ to the endpoints of $e_2$; this seems like a problem that would be just as hard as the general problem!

Comment: @MishaLavrov That sounds right, but is it though ? I'm unable to prove that if two graphs that differs by only an edge have an isomorphism, then they have an isomorphism associating the endpoints of the differing edges?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Indeed, I found a counter-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is harder than finding an automorphism fixing two vertex associations.

Let $G(V, E)$ be a graph, and let $u_1, u_2, v_1, v_2 \in V$ be vertices such that we want to find if there is an automorphism bringing $u_1$ to $v_1$ and $u_2$ to $v_2$.

We replace every edge of $G$ with two arcs pointing in opposite directions. We replace each arc with an undirected gadget sufficient to ensure that arcs must be mapped to arcs. We thus get a new graph $\widetilde{G}$.

We define $e_1 = u_1v_1$ and $e_2 = u_2v_2$. $\widetilde{G}\cup e_1$ and $\widetilde{G}\cup e_2$ are isomorphic only if $G$ has an automorphism bringing $u_1$ to $v_1$ and $u_2$ to $v_2$.

It is easy to show that finding an automorphism fixing two vertex associations is harder than finding an automorphism.

Graph automorphism may be easier than graph isomorphism, but currently, we don't have asymptotically better algorithms for graph automorphism than for graph isomorphism. I was unable to show that this problem is complete for the Graph Automorphism class.

Note that it is necessary to build a $\widetilde{G}$ for the reduction since we can find some counterexamples such that $G\cup e_1$ and $G\cup e_2$ are isomorphic but have no isomorphism sending $e_1$ to $e_2$:[image]

Comment: Isn't graph isomorphism reducible to graph automorphism by asking whether the disjoint union $G \cup H$ (or its complement, if we want something connected) has an automorphism swapping $G$ and $H$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Asking to swap $G$ and $H$ is more difficult than asking for just an automorphism. However, we know than Graph Isomorphism is equivalent to find a set of generators for the graph automorphism group. AFAIK, there is no known reduction for existence of just one automorphism.

Comment: You can see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019079900048?via%3Dihub for the equivalence

Comment: But if you can find a set of generators, then you can test if there is an automorphism swapping $G \cup H$ (in this case) by testing if any of the generators do so.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, but if you ask for only one non-trivial automorphism instead of all the generators, then it might be easier.